# Trying to display button click results on screen

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner trying to create an online calculator in JS. I made buttons, looped through them, and then created a function that looks to click and display numbers on the screen with innerHTML of the screen. but It is saying undefined. Here is the code.

```
var screen = document.getElementById("screen")
var allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons');



for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', pressButton)
}

function pressButton(event){
    var numID = this.id; // activates ID for each button the event listener above
    screen.innerHTML = numID;


};
```

Comment: declare <div id="screen"></div>  in html page .. replace to screen.textContent = numID;

Comment: add your HTML so that we can have a better idea of what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example of how you could do it:

```js
const screen = document.getElementById("screen")
const allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('buttons');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(allButtons, (e) => e.addEventListener('click', () => screen.innerHTML += e.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="buttons">Button1 </div>
<div class="buttons">Button2 </div>
<div class="buttons">Button3 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!! @neegol

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the id attribute to all the buttons you created? It is possible that it is saying undefined cause it can't find the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calc.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <textarea id="screen" placeholder="0"></textarea>
    <div class="buttonswrap">
        <button id="num1" class= "buttons" value="1">1</button>
        <button id="num2" class= "buttons" value="2">2</button>
        <button id="num3" class= "buttons" value="3">3</button>
        <button id="num4" class= "buttons" value="4">4</button>
        <br>
        <button id="num5" class= "buttons" value="5">5</button>
        <button id="num6" class= "buttons" value="6">6</button>
        <button id="num7" class= "buttons" value="7">7</button>
        <button id="num8" class= "buttons" value="8">8</button>
        <br>
        <button id="num9" class= "buttons" value="9">9</button>
        <button id="num0" class= "buttons" value="0">0</button>
        <button id="plus" class= "buttons" value="+">+</button>
        <button id="multiply" class= "buttons" value="*">*</button>
        <br>
        <button id="divide" class= "buttons" value="/">/</button>
        <button id="minus" class= "buttons"  value="-">-</button>
        <button id="point" class= "buttons"  value=".">.</button>
        <button id="equals" class= "buttons"  value="=">=</button>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my HTML